# Android: Free Cropping of Image

Tags: android

I want to do free style of cropping on Image...[image: Free Cropping]
where image can be from Gallery or Can be from Camera...

is there any solution regarding this?

Comment: Have you used surface view before?

Comment: @kabuto178 Not yet...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Load image from gallery or camera on View (Using Canvas Draw image)

  ```
   public class SomeView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
      private Paint paint;
      public static List<Point> points;
      int DIST = 2;
      boolean flgPathDraw = true;

      Point mfirstpoint = null;
      boolean bfirstpoint = false;

      Point mlastpoint = null;

      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
              R.drawable.gallery_12);
      Context mContext;

      public SomeView(Context c) {
          super(c);

          mContext = c;
          setFocusable(true);
          setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

          paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
          paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
          paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
          paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
          paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

          this.setOnTouchListener(this);
          points = new ArrayList<Point>();

          bfirstpoint = false;
      }

      public SomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          mContext = context;
          setFocusable(true);
          setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

          paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
          paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
          paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
          paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

          this.setOnTouchListener(this);
          points = new ArrayList<Point>();
          bfirstpoint = false;

      }

      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

          Path path = new Path();
          boolean first = true;

          for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {
              Point point = points.get(i);
              if (first) {
                  first = false;
                  path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
              } else if (i < points.size() - 1) {
                  Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                  path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
              } else {
                  mlastpoint = points.get(i);
                  path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
              }
          }
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }

      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
          // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
          // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

          Point point = new Point();
          point.x = (int) event.getX();
          point.y = (int) event.getY();

          if (flgPathDraw) {

              if (bfirstpoint) {

                  if (comparepoint(mfirstpoint, point)) {
                      // points.add(point);
                      points.add(mfirstpoint);
                          flgPathDraw = false;
                                          showcropdialog();
                  } else {
                      points.add(point);
                  }
              } else {
                  points.add(point);
              }

              if (!(bfirstpoint)) {

                  mfirstpoint = point;
                  bfirstpoint = true;
              }
          }

          invalidate();
          Log.e("Hi  ==>", "Size: " + point.x + " " + point.y);

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
              Log.d("Action up*******~~~~~~~>>>>", "called");
              mlastpoint = point;
              if (flgPathDraw) {
                  if (points.size() > 12) {
                      if (!comparepoint(mfirstpoint, mlastpoint)) {
                          flgPathDraw = false;
                          points.add(mfirstpoint);
                          showcropdialog();
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          return true;
      }

      private boolean comparepoint(Point first, Point current) {
          int left_range_x = (int) (current.x - 3);
          int left_range_y = (int) (current.y - 3);

          int right_range_x = (int) (current.x + 3);
          int right_range_y = (int) (current.y + 3);

          if ((left_range_x < first.x && first.x < right_range_x)
                  && (left_range_y < first.y && first.y < right_range_y)) {
              if (points.size() < 10) {
                  return false;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
          } else {
              return false;
          }

      }

      public void fillinPartofPath() {
          Point point = new Point();
          point.x = points.get(0).x;
          point.y = points.get(0).y;

          points.add(point);
          invalidate();
      }

      public void resetView() {
          points.clear();
          paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
          flgPathDraw = true;
          invalidate();
      }

      private void showcropdialog() {
          DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  Intent intent;
                  switch (which) {
                  case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                      // Yes button clicked
                      // bfirstpoint = false;

                      intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtra("crop", true);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);
                      break;

                  case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                      // No button clicked

                      intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtra("crop", false);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);

                      bfirstpoint = false;
                      // resetView();

                      break;
                  }
              }
          };

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
          builder.setMessage("Do you Want to save Crop or Non-crop image?")
                  .setPositiveButton("Crop", dialogClickListener)
                  .setNegativeButton("Non-crop", dialogClickListener).show()
                  .setCancelable(false);
      }
     }


  class Point {

      public float dy;
      public float dx;
      float x, y;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return x + ", " + y;
      }
  }
  ```
- MainActivity Which call Someview to draw/load image

  ```
  public class MainActivity_ extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      setContentView(new SomeView(MainActivity_.this));
  }

  }
  ```
- CropActivity : which load crop image on bitmap.

  ```
   public class CropActivity extends Activity {

      ImageView compositeImageView;
      boolean crop;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.cropview);

          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          if (extras != null) {
              crop = extras.getBoolean("crop");
          }
          int widthOfscreen = 0;
          int heightOfScreen = 0;

          DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
          try {
              getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
          }
          widthOfscreen = dm.widthPixels;
          heightOfScreen = dm.heightPixels;

          compositeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.our_imageview);

          Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                  R.drawable.gallery_12);

          Bitmap resultingImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthOfscreen,
                  heightOfScreen, bitmap2.getConfig());

          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);
          Paint paint = new Paint();
          paint.setAntiAlias(true);

          Path path = new Path();
          for (int i = 0; i < SomeView.points.size(); i++) {
              path.lineTo(SomeView.points.get(i).x, SomeView.points.get(i).y);
          }
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
          if (crop) {
              paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

          } else {
              paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
          }
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
          compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I used this but not able to get the Bitmap from cropped area.while saving its contains background with cropped image.

Comment: @noviceAndroid can you tell me how i can get the bitmap from cropped area? and how to avoid extra area around the image while getting bitmap

Comment: if you want to remove extra part just remove transpert portion of bitmap so you can get orignal crop image .

Comment: @noviceAndroid How to do this in onDraw instead of creating another bitmap in CropActivity - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943983/android-crop-bitmap-canvas?noredirect=1#comment61446920_36943983.

Comment: I want to implement manual, square, circle and shape cropping functionality. So do you have the reference for the complete library?