# Get the free hand cropping Image From the original in android

Tags: java, android, image

[Android: Free Croping of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439246/android-free-croping-of-image)
Prefer this link to crop the image.

But my problem is when the crop the image than remain part of the original image are black. so how can i remove that black part?

i have use :

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Imagepath,options);

    Bitmap resultingImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap2, Xmin, Ymin, Width, Height);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);
```

here i have get the Xmin,Ymin,Width,Height using this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693229/need-help-finding-minimum-x-and-y-values-in-an-arraylist-of-points-java

But I have does not create bounding of cropping image... Please Anyone can help me?

Thanx in Advance....