# Cropping image in irregular shape in android not working proper

Tags: android, crop, ontouch

Hi people I am using a [FlexiCrop](https://github.com/coderush/FlexiCrop) andtrying to crop image in irregular shape my code for activity is looks like this

```
public class CropActivity 
extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView drawImageView;
    private Bitmap sourceBitmap;
    private Path clipPath;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 2;

    Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap alteredBitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    Matrix matrix;
    float downx = 0;
    float downy = 0;
    float upx = 0;
    float upy = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.crop);
        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    try {
                        //use standard intent to capture an image
                        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                        startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                    } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
        Button saveButton   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        Button discardButton    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_discard);

        drawImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DrawImageView);
        drawImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(Math.round(Math.random()*100000))+".jpg");
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    alteredBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();

                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(StickersCreator.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Saved");
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                    //Now deleting the temporary file created on camera capture
                    File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        f.delete();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        discardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                    //Now deleting the temporary file created on camera capture
                    File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        f.delete();
                    }

                    getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                    mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    //resetting the image view
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DrawImageView);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(null);


                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
        switch (requestCode) {

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                doCrop();
                break;

            case CAMERA_CAPTURE:
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                doCrop();
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          downx = event.getX();
          downy = event.getY();
          clipPath = new Path();
          clipPath.moveTo(downx, downy);
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          clipPath.lineTo(upx, upy);
          drawImageView.invalidate();
          downx = upx;
          downy = upy;
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
          clipPath.lineTo(upx, upy);
          drawImageView.invalidate();
          cropImageByPath();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void cropImageByPath() {
        //closing the path now.
        clipPath.close();
        //setting the fill type to inverse, so that the outer part of the selected path gets filled.
        clipPath.setFillType(FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
        Paint xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        xferPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPath(clipPath, xferPaint);
        xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(alteredBitmap, 0, 0, xferPaint);
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        try {
                sourceBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageCaptureUri);
                BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        mImageCaptureUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        mImageCaptureUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                    .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
                canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                matrix = new Matrix();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
                //loading the image bitmap in image view
                drawImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
                //setting the touch listener
                drawImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

It is cropping image but when i draw shape for cropping shape drawing start from far away point from where i touched and draw shape it draw shape upside from i have touched the view please any on can suggest what is wrong i am doing here

[image]
 firs is the original image  and on it when i draw a very big circle on key board it crops very far away from key board and very small circle second image 
I darwed a circle on keyboard but it cropped from upside and also size of circle is very small

[image]

Comment: if possible attach screenshots

Comment: I have atteched screens and description please take a look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Free Croping of Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439246/android-free-croping-of-image)

Comment: check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439246/android-free-croping-of-image

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is not working for me

Comment: what is happening with that solution?

Comment: when i start main activity it gives me this exception      10-04 11:09:35.933: E/AndroidRuntime(8171): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
10-04 11:09:35.933: E/AndroidRuntime(8171):  at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1224)
10-04 11:09:35.933: E/AndroidRuntime(8171):  at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:579)
10-04 11:09:35.933: E/AndroidRuntime(8171):  at com.photo.stickers.base.views.SomeView.onDraw(SomeView.java:80)
Error is in ondraw it says

Comment: I resolved issues but the image on someview goes out of screen if image size is greaterthen screen size

Comment: yes that you have to do some trick. as this code lacking this

Comment: but how could you help me please i am trying since morning but if i fit the bitmap on canvas then cut area differs automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved and completely set this cropping and saving of image using [Android: Free Croping of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439246/android-free-croping-of-image) with some modifications for choosing images and fitting images in screen by my self and my code is modifications are as under

```
public class SomeView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private Paint paint;
public static List<Point> points;
int DIST = 2;
boolean flgPathDraw = true;
public Uri orignalUri;
float origianlheight=0.0f,originalwidth=0.0f,heightratio=0.0f,widthratio=0.0f;
public static int REQUEST_CODE=2;
Point mfirstpoint = null;
boolean bfirstpoint = false;

Point mlastpoint = null;
boolean cropflag=false;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg_crop);
Context mContext;


public void setBitmap(Bitmap bmp,Uri uri){
    orignalUri=uri;
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    origianlheight=bmp.getHeight();
    originalwidth=bmp.getWidth();
    //if(origianlheight>originalwidth){
        heightratio=height/origianlheight;
  //  }else{
        widthratio=width/originalwidth;
  //  }
    bitmap=bmp;
    bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth()*widthratio),(int)(bmp.getHeight()*heightratio), true);

 // bitmap=bmp;
  paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
  paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
  paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

  flgPathDraw = true;
  this.setOnTouchListener(this);
  points = new ArrayList<Point>();
  bfirstpoint = false;
  cropflag=false;

}
public void clear(){
     setFocusable(true);
     setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
     paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
     paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     this.setOnTouchListener(this);
     points = new ArrayList<Point>();

     bfirstpoint = false;
     flgPathDraw = true;
     cropflag=false;
     invalidate();
}

public SomeView(Context c) {
    super(c);

    mContext = c;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    origianlheight=bitmap.getHeight();
    originalwidth=bitmap.getWidth();
    //if(origianlheight>originalwidth){
        heightratio=height/origianlheight;
  //  }else{
        widthratio=width/originalwidth;
  //  }
    bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(originalwidth*widthratio),(int)(origianlheight*heightratio), true);



    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    bfirstpoint = false;
    flgPathDraw = true;
    cropflag=false;
}

public SomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    origianlheight=bitmap.getHeight();
    originalwidth=bitmap.getWidth();
    //if(origianlheight>originalwidth){
        heightratio=height/origianlheight;
  //  }else{
        widthratio=width/originalwidth;
  //  }
    bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(originalwidth*widthratio),(int)(origianlheight*heightratio), true);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    bfirstpoint = false;
    flgPathDraw = true;
    cropflag=false;


}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,paint);

    Path path = new Path();
    boolean first = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {
        Point point = points.get(i);
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        } else if (i < points.size() - 1) {
            Point next = points.get(i + 1);
            path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
        } else {
            mlastpoint = points.get(i);
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();

    if (flgPathDraw) {

        if (bfirstpoint) {

            if (comparepoint(mfirstpoint, point)) {
                // points.add(point);
                points.add(mfirstpoint);
                    flgPathDraw = false;
                                 //  showcropdialog();
                    cropflag=true;
            } else {
                points.add(point);
            }
        } else {
            points.add(point);
        }

        if (!(bfirstpoint)) {

            mfirstpoint = point;
            bfirstpoint = true;
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    Log.e("Hi  ==>", "Size: " + point.x + " " + point.y);

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("Action up*******~~~~~~~>>>>", "called");
        mlastpoint = point;
        if (flgPathDraw) {
            if (points.size() > 12) {
                if (!comparepoint(mfirstpoint, mlastpoint)) {
                    flgPathDraw = false;
                    points.add(mfirstpoint);
                   // showcropdialog();
                    cropflag=true;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean comparepoint(Point first, Point current) {
    int left_range_x = (int) (current.x - 3);
    int left_range_y = (int) (current.y - 3);

    int right_range_x = (int) (current.x + 3);
    int right_range_y = (int) (current.y + 3);

    if ((left_range_x < first.x && first.x < right_range_x)
            && (left_range_y < first.y && first.y < right_range_y)) {
        if (points.size() < 10) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public void fillinPartofPath() {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = points.get(0).x;
    point.y = points.get(0).y;

    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
}

public void resetView() {
    points.clear();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    flgPathDraw = true;
    invalidate();
}

 /*  private void showcropdialog() {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // Yes button clicked
                // bfirstpoint = false;

                intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("crop", true);
                intent.putExtra("heightratio", heightratio);
                intent.putExtra("widthratio", widthratio);
                intent.putExtra("URI", orignalUri.toString());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // No button clicked

                intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("crop", false);
                intent.putExtra("heightratio", heightratio);
                intent.putExtra("widthratio", widthratio);
                intent.putExtra("URI", orignalUri.toString());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

                bfirstpoint = false;
                // resetView();

                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Do you Want to save Crop or Non-crop image?")
            .setPositiveButton("Crop", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Non-crop", dialogClickListener).show()
            .setCancelable(false);
}*/

public void Crop(){
    if(cropflag){
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("crop", true);
        intent.putExtra("heightratio", heightratio);
        intent.putExtra("widthratio", widthratio);
        intent.putExtra("URI", orignalUri.toString());
        ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

}
I made changes in this class according croping image and setting bitmap dynamically

next is activity which uses some view in design xml like

```
public class StickersCreator 
extends Activity{
ImageButton btnCapture,btnChooseFromlib,btnClear;
Button btnCrop;
SomeView someView;
private static final String RESULT_BUNDLE_EXTAS = "RESULT_BUNDLE_EXTAS";
private static final String RESULT_BUNDLE_DATA = "RESULT_BUNDLE_DATA";
private static final String RESULT_BUNDLE_REQUEST_CODE = "RESULT_BUNDLE_REQUEST_CODE";
private static final String RESULT_BUNDLE_RESULT_CODE = "RESULT_BUNDLE_RESULT_CODE";

private static final int REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CROP=2;
private Uri captureImageUri;
private Bundle resultBundle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stickers_creator);
    btnCrop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCrop);
    btnCapture=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.BtnCapture);
    btnClear=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnChooseFromlib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnChoosefromLib);
    someView=(SomeView)findViewById(R.id.someView);
    btnCrop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            someView.Crop();
        }
    });
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            someView.clear();

        }
    });
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureImageUri = null;
            try {
                String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (TextUtils.equals(storageState, Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath()
                            + File.separatorChar
                            + "Android/data/"
                            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                            + "/files/";
                    File directory = new File(path);
                    directory.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(directory,
                            Integer.toHexString((int) System
                                    .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    file.createNewFile();

                    captureImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, captureImageUri);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.w("FrameEditor",
                            "Can not create temp file for image capture "
                                    + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);


        }
    });

    btnChooseFromlib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
    resultBundle = new Bundle();
    if (intent != null) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        resultBundle.putBundle(RESULT_BUNDLE_EXTAS, extras);
        Uri uriData = intent.getData();
        if (uriData != null) {
            resultBundle.putParcelable(RESULT_BUNDLE_DATA, uriData);
        }
    }

    resultBundle.putInt(RESULT_BUNDLE_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
    resultBundle.putInt(RESULT_BUNDLE_RESULT_CODE, resultCode);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    handleActivityResult();
}

private void handleActivityResult() {
    if (resultBundle == null) {
        return;
    }
    int requestCode = resultBundle.getInt(RESULT_BUNDLE_REQUEST_CODE);
    int resultCode = resultBundle.getInt(RESULT_BUNDLE_RESULT_CODE);
    Uri dataUri = resultBundle.getParcelable(RESULT_BUNDLE_DATA);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (dataUri != null) {

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
                someView.setBitmap(bitmap1,uri);
                // Intend for EditorActivity

            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (captureImageUri != null) {
                // Intend for EditorActivity

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), captureImageUri);
                    someView.setBitmap(bitmap,captureImageUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
        break;

    }
    case REQUEST_CROP:{
        }
    }
    }
    resultBundle = null;

}

}
```

this stickers creator activity allow user for clearing cropping and selecting image from media or capturing image and then cropping image also

```
public class CropActivity extends Activity {
ImageView compositeImageView;
boolean crop;

Bitmap resultingImage;
Uri imageUri;
Button btnDone,btnCancel;
float heightratio=0.0f,widthratio=0.0f;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);

    btnDone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(CropActivity.this, StickersCreator.class);
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });
    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int widthOfscreen = 0;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {

                Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                String ts = tsLong.toString();

                File Filename=new File(getFilesDir(),ts+".png");
                //File Filename1=new File(getFilesDir(),"EPICBATTLE"+((Long)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)).toString()+"_ico.png");
                out = new FileOutputStream(Filename);
                resultingImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(CropActivity.this, StickersCreator.class);
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();

        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        crop = extras.getBoolean("crop");
        heightratio=extras.getFloat("heightratio");
        widthratio=extras.getFloat("widthratio");
        imageUri=Uri.parse(extras.getString("URI"));
       // byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
       // bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    }
    int widthOfscreen = 0;
    int heightOfScreen = 0;

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    try {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    widthOfscreen = dm.widthPixels;
    heightOfScreen = dm.heightPixels;

    compositeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Bitmap bitmap2=null;
    try {

        bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, (int)(bitmap2.getWidth()*widthratio),(int)(bitmap2.getHeight()*heightratio), true);

    resultingImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthOfscreen,
            heightOfScreen, bitmap2.getConfig());
   // resultingImage=CropBitmapTransparency(resultingImage);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Path path = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < SomeView.points.size(); i++) {
        path.lineTo(SomeView.points.get(i).x, SomeView.points.get(i).y);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    if (crop) {
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

    } else {
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
    resultingImage=CropBitmapTransparency(resultingImage);
    compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);//setImageBitmap(resultingImage);
}

Bitmap CropBitmapTransparency(Bitmap sourceBitmap){
    int minX = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    int minY = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
    int maxX = -1;
    int maxY = -1;
    for(int y = 0; y < sourceBitmap.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourceBitmap.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            int alpha = (sourceBitmap.getPixel(x, y) >> 24) & 255;
            if(alpha > 0)   // pixel is not 100% transparent
            {
                if(x < minX)
                    minX = x;
                if(x > maxX)
                    maxX = x;
                if(y < minY)
                    minY = y;
                if(y > maxY)
                    maxY = y;
            }
        }
    }
    if((maxX < minX) || (maxY < minY))
        return null; // Bitmap is entirely transparent

    // crop bitmap to non-transparent area and return:
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, minX, minY, (maxX - minX) + 1, (maxY - minY) + 1);
}
```

}

this crop activity saves cropped image in internal memory while pressing done button